# Singleton holding multiple ADODB connections

Tags: php, mysql, singleton, adodb

A legacy website is exhibiting unexpected behavior with it's database connections. The application connects to several MySQL databases on the same server and the original developer created a "singleton" class that holds connection objects for each of them.

Lately we have been encountering a strange behavior with the class: when a connection to `www` is created after creating `extra`, getting the instance of `extra` returns a connection that has the correct parameters when viewed with `var_dump()` but is actually connected to the `www` database.

What could cause this? The code has worked before at some stage. Creating a new connection on each call to `getInstance()` fixes the problem but I'd like to solve this the right way if possible.

```
<?php

class DBConnection
{
    private static $default;
    private static $extra;
    private static $intra;
    private static $www;

    public static function getInstance($dbname = "default")
    {
        global $db; // This is an array containing database connection parameters

        if(!($dbname == "default" || $dbname == "extra" || $dbname == "www" || $dbname == "intra"))
        {
            $dbname = "default";
        }

        if (empty(self::$$dbname)) // Making this pass every time fixes the problem
        {
            try
            {
                self::$$dbname = ADONewConnection('mysqlt');
                if(isset($db[$dbname]))
                {
                    self::$$dbname->connect(DBHOSTNAME, $db[$dbname]["dbusername"], $db[$dbname]["dbpassword"], $db[$dbname]["dbname"]);
                }
                else 
                {
                    // fallback
                    self::$$dbname->connect(DBHOSTNAME, DBUSERNAME, DBPASSWORD, DBNAME);
                }

                self::$$dbname->SetFetchMode(ADODB_FETCH_ASSOC);
                self::$$dbname->execute("SET NAMES utf8");

                return self::$$dbname;
            }
            catch(Exception $e)
            {
                exit("DB connection failed");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return self::$$dbname;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a simplified example of the class misbehaving:

```
$cn = DBConnection::getInstance("extra");
$cn->debug = true;
$rs = $cn->execute("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE id = ".$this->id);
```

The last line fails with the error message "Table www.messages does not exist".

Comment: Can you share the code that makes you believe `extra` practically points to `www`?

Comment: @Passerby: Code example added.

Answer (score 0):

1: You don't need to establish connection in getInstance().
getInstance must not do anything, but return instance of DB class.

2: when you do `self::$$dbname->connect(`, `if (empty(self::$$dbname))` will return you false next time you call it.

Singleton is described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

What you have - it's just a static method.

Comment: If `empty(self::$$dbname)` evaluates to `false`, `getInstance()` returns the previously instantiated connection object, as is expected of a singleton. The difference is that instead of one instance there are four possible instances.